# Evolution <-> U1: How can I solve problem with syncing?

Tags: ubuntu-one, evolution

When I was trying to sync my Evolution Contacts with U1 I'got the following error message:

> GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._e_2ddata_2dbook_2derror.Code100: Cannot open book: Could not create DesktopcouchSession object

What does that mean and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/evolution-couchdb/+bug/727370

Answer (score 2):

From the bug report I put in the comment post [#44](https://bugs.launchpad.net/evolution-couchdb/+bug/727370/comments/44) includes a [proposal for a fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/evolution-couchdb/+bug/727370/comments/44)

And the fix would be:

```
bzr get lp:~rodrigo-moya/ubuntu/natty/evolution-couchdb/idle-loading
cd idle-loading
bzr bd -- -b
```

(bzr is probably not installed. If you want to try this first do `sudo apt-get install bzr`)
Use at own risc!